# Equivalence of $\pi$ is the first positive zero of the taylor series for $\sin(x)$ and $\pi/4 = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

For $x\in\mathbb{R}$, define $\sin (x) = x - x^3/3!+x^5/5!-\cdots$ and $\pi = 4(1-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5} -\frac{1}{7}+\cdots)$. Then show that $\sin(\pi/2) = 1$

In the prologue of *Real and Complex Analysis* by Walter Rudin, pi is defined as the first positive zero of the series defined as $\sin(x)$; I want to check that pi is same as above defined Pi.

Comment: the expansion is $\sin (x) = x - x^3/3!+x^5/5!-\cdots$

Comment: Is there any particular motivation for this problem?  Any reason you'd like to do things in an ostensibly backwards fashion?

Comment: @janmarqz updated...

Comment: Hi and welcome! What have you tried so far?

Comment: the update is still wrong for the sin(x)-expansion, and I don't downvote ever :D . If you correct this I would upvote

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Yes, in the prologue of Real and complex analysis by Walter Rudin, pi is defined as the first positive zero of the series defined as sin(x); I want to check that pi is same as above defined Pi.

Comment: @janmarqz i guess now it is correct.. :)

Comment: as you can see a big amount of concentration is needed to do maths, good-luck! Remember to upvote me as you could! :D

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with the question as it stands now. i would like to know the answer to this question.

Comment: @Iuʇǝƃɹɐʇoɹ, i checked the link. i don't see the relevance. the problem is self contained. with the series for $"\pi/4"$ given  and the series for $\sin,$ can you show that $\sin 2"\pi/4" = 1.$

Comment: I've put a draft of a solution [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/10126/194204) in case this gets reopened.

Comment: @aes Thanks for that draft. I got some hint and ideas :)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a detailed outline for how to do this in a fairly standard line of development of trig functions from their power series definitions.

(A "plug in" combinatorial proof would be neat to see as well, of course.)

Step 1. Show the basic trig identities (double angle formulas and $\sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2 = 1$) for the taylor series definitions of $\sin(x)$ and $\cos(x)$.

[The double angle formulas are nice to prove using the power series for $e^x$. The second is immediate upon differentiation.]

Step 2. Let $pi$ (not the greek symbol for now) be the first root of $\sin(x)$. From the derivative of $\sin(x)$ at zero and the intermediate value theorem, we get that $\sin(x) > 0$ for $0 < x < pi$.

Step 3. Use trig identities to show that $\sin(2x) = 0$ if and only if $\sin(x) = 0$ or $\cos(x) = 0$. Conclude that $x = pi/2$ is the first time $\cos(x) = 0$.

Step 4. Let $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$. Show that $\frac{d}{dx} \tan(x) = \frac{1}{\cos(x)^2}$. Conclude that $\tan(x)$ is well-defined, increasing, and unbounded on $(-pi/2,pi/2)$.

Step 5. Define $\arctan(x)$ to be the inverse of $\tan(x): (-pi/2,pi/2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Show that $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$ from trig identities.

Step 6. Show that $\arctan(x) = x - \frac{x^3}{3} + \frac{x^5}{5} - \frac{x^7}{7} + \cdots$ from the series expansion for $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ and differentiation of power series theorems and the fact that $\tan(0) = 0$. This converges and hence is valid on $(-1,1)$.

Step 7. The series also converges for $x = 1$ and hence (by a theorem on power series convergence), we get $\arctan(1) = 1 - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{7} + \ldots$. Thus it remains to show $2 \arctan(1) = pi/2$.

Step 8. Show from trig identities that $\tan(x) = \pm 1$ if and only if $\sin(x) = \pm \cos(x)$ if and only if $\cos(2x) = 0$. Conclude that $2 \arctan(1) = pi/2$, as desired (because $2 \arctan(1)$ must be the first zero of $\cos(x)$).

Comment: can you start from $at(x) = \int_0^x {dt \over 1 + t^2}$ so that you have $at(pi/4) = 1$. then define $tan()$ and $\sin$.  here $at()$ is stand in for $\tan^{-1}()$ function.

Comment: I’m not an analyst, but my understanding is that it’s a moderately deep result that the endpoint-evaluation of the series for $\arctan(x)$ gives $\arctan(1)$.

Comment: @Lubin It's called Abel's theorem, and is Theorem 8.2 in Rudin (the textbook OP is using).

Comment: @abel That's fairly close to what I described. The whole "start from somewhere" idea is equivalent to "prove these two things are the same."

Comment: An addendum to the Rudin reference: that was to _Principles of Mathematical Analysis_ by Rudin, which is more basic than _Real and Complex Analysis_, which I now see is what OP refers to.

Comment: @aes, thanks for filling in for my ignorance.

Comment: At step 2, how are we sure that there exists a smallest positive root? How can we be sure it's not something like the function $g:\mathbf{R}\setminus\{0\}\to\mathbf{R}$ defined by $g(x):= x\sin{(1/x)}$, which has no smallest positive root?

Answer (score 0):

first attempt: i don't have an answer but here are some thoughts on this problem. Let 
$$S = x - x^3/3! + x^5/5!-\cdots \mbox{ and }C = 1 - x^2/2! + x^4/4! - \cdots $$

(a) derive differential equations $\frac{dS}{dx} = C, \frac{dC}{dx} = -S$

(b) show $S^2 + C^2 = 1$

(c) establish that $C > 0, S > 0 \mbox{ for some $\delta > 0$ and } 0 < x < \delta $

---

i don't see how to use the series for $\pi.$

here is my second attempt at using the series for $\pi.$  define a function $t$ by 
$$ t = \int_0^m {du \over 1 + u^2}, -\infty < m < \infty$$ 
we will first establish:

(a) $\ t(\infty) = 2t(1)$

(b) $\ t(1) = \pi/4, t(\infty) = \pi/2$

(c) $\ t$ is an odd function and is increasing on $(-\infty, \infty)$

(d) $\displaystyle {dt \over dm} = {1 \over 1 + m^2}$

proof of (a):

$\begin{eqnarray} t(\infty) &=&\int_0^\infty {du \over 1 + u^2}= t(1) + \int_1^\infty{du \over 1 + u^2} = f(1) + \int_1^0 {d(1/u) \over 1 + (1/u)^2}\\
&=& t(1) + \int_0^1 {du \over 1 + u^2} = 2t(1).
\end{eqnarray}$

$$t(1) = \int_0^1 {du \over 1 + u^2} = \int_0^1 (1 - u^2 + u^4 + \cdots) du
= \{u - u^3/3 + u^5/5 + \cdots  \}|_0^1 = \pi/4$$

Now we define $m$ on $-\pi/2, \pi/2)$ as the inverse function of $t.$ then $m$ has the following properties:

(a) $m$ is odd and increasing on $(-\pi/2, \pi/2)$

(b) $m(0) = 0, m(\pi/4) = 1, m(\pi/2 -) = \infty$

(c) $\displaystyle {dm \over dt} = 1 + m^2$

now define $$c = {1 \over \sqrt{ 1 + m^2}} \mbox{ on the interval } 0 \le t < \pi/2  \mbox{ set } c(\pi/2) = 0 \mbox{ to make it continuous at } t = \pi/2. $$

My aim is to show the generic properties of $c = \cos$ and to find the Mclaurin series expansion about $x = 0$

I will get back to it later, but if someone wants to continue they are welcome to do so.

---

The properties of $m$ makes
$$c(0) = 1, c(\pi/4) = 1/\sqrt 2, c(\pi/2) = 0,  c \mbox{ is decreasing } 0 \le x \le \pi/2.$$

We will establish the Mclaurin series of $c$ by finding second order differential equation satisfied by $c.$

Differentiating $ c^2(1+m^2) = 1$ and using ${dm \over dt} =  1 + m^2,$ we find that $c$ satisfies the differential equation $${dc \over dt} = -mc$$ We also have $\frac{dc}{dt} = 0$ at $t = 0.$  Differentiating once more

$$ {d^2c \over dt^2 } = -c, \ c(0) = 1,\ c^\prime(0) = 0 $$ which gives the series $$c = 1 - t^2/2! + t^4/4! + \cdots $$ and we have shown that $$c(\pi/2) = 0$$ where $\pi$ is defined by $$\pi/4 = 1 - 1/3 + 1/5 + \cdots. $$

If one needs things about $\sin$ define $\sin = \sqrt{1-c^2}$ and derive a similar
second order differential equation for $s$.